# Getting error while invoking the chrome browser using selenium

Tags: selenium

This is the error I am getting while running a selenium program

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    at org.openqa.selenium.internal.Require$StateChecker.nonNull(Require.java:280)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:135)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:38)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:231)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:437)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:127)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:46)
    at Selintroduction.main(Selintroduction.java:17)
```

Comment: What code you are trying?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.